# How do I properly change the values of a Radiobutton?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button

I have created a IntVar() this.v.
When this.v = 1, my elif statement is true, which should not be the case.
What have I done wrong?
When I print(this.v.get()) the value returned is 1.
(import tkinter)

```
this.v = IntVar()
this.button1 = Radiobutton(this.root,text = "Small Boxes First",variable = this.v,value = 1)
this.button1.grid(row = 2,column = 5)
this.button2 = Radiobutton(this.root,text = "Large Boxes First",variable = this.v,value = 2)
this.button2.grid(row = 3,column = 5)

def packNSaveClicked(this):
        if(int(this.wid.get()) <= 0 or int(this.len.get()) <= 0 or this.len.get() == '' or this.wid.get() == ''):
            messagebox.showerror("Truck Size Error", "The length or width of the Truck is not a valid value!")
        elif(int(this.v.get()) != 1 or int(this.v.get()) != 2):
           #ALWAYS SHOWING UP, even though print statement prints out 1 or 2
            print(this.v.get())
            messagebox.showerror("Packing Error", "Pack algorithm not selected!")
        else:
          ...(this code not relevant)
```

Comment: Please add the GUI toolkit used and define "are not working" You might have to pay them more to make them working ...

Comment: What''s happening is that the elif statement is running when it should not be. When I print the value of "v" it is 1 or 2, but the elif statement runs anyways. I'm using tkinter, I'll edit to specify

Comment: Should be updated, let me double check.

Comment: Note: It is not to required parenthesize conditions for `if`, etc. in Python, is is actually strongly discouraged to do. Notice, that in `for` it is actually not even possible. Do not try Python code to look "C-ish"!

Comment: "The if statements are running" ... I assume you mean the conditions are true? Just print the values. Note there is only a single `if` statement. So, which condition is actually true?

Comment: the "if" statement is false. The "elif" statement is true, but it should be false. I printed the value and "v" is 1. The elif statement still runs, which is the problem. If the value of "v" is 1 it should go to else, but for some reason it isn't.

Comment: Basically what is happening is:  1.    I select a radio button, it sets the value of v to 1.       2.       The code goes to the elif statement, and this.v.get() returns one. The elif statement runs when it should not, and my print statement proves that the value of "v" is 1.

Comment: Again: please _improve_ your question, providing the necessary information. It is nonsense to have all that in the comments here. However: do not _change_ the question's focus.

Comment: Check all values of the conditions! Not the first compare of `if` will raise an exception if the value is `''`.

Comment: I have tried to place the print statement in different places to make sure the values don't change. I have double checked my conditions, and they make sense. Unfortunately, this is a strange semantic error.

Comment: @Olaf: "Note: It is not to required parenthesize conditions for if, etc. in Python, _is is actually strongly discouraged to do._" Where is this strongly discouraged? One should _always_ use parenthesis unless there's a single condition.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Please have a closer look, _where_ the parenthesis actually are (hint: I mean the outermost). That is neither required, not encouraged (but the opposite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `elif` will always trigger, as a variable cannot be `!= 1` *and* `!=2` at the same time!

That is not a "semantic error", but a logical error by the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "do this if x is not 1, OR do this if x is not 2", it will always run. Consider the following values:

- 0 (zero): it is not 1, so the elif test passes
- 1 (one): it is one but it is it is not 2, so the elif test passes
- 2 (two): it is not 1, so the elif test passes
- 3 (three): it is not 1, so the elif test passes